# Cipher I found: O_OO|O#|~#|OO%|

Tags: cipher

Here is the cipher you need to solve, it is an actual English text:

```
O_OO|O#|~#|OO%|O_#|O#O#O|[#_|O_O|OOO#|[/#/|%#|#|O/O/O|O/O/OO%|O%O#|O%#OO|OO_O|O%|O#O#|O|[O#O|OOO_O|[O%O#O|_|[O##|[OO|%O|O_#|###|[#OO%O|O%%OO|#OOO|/O/O%O|O//OO/#/|/#
```

---

Hints:

> "|" is for separating letters, "[" is for space.
>
>  With that same encryption method "Hello" is:
>
>  `O#|#%|OO|#%_%/#/|O_O`

---

Source: Discord private chat.

Comment: I got this cipher from some discord server and posted after it was corrected by the author in PM. Since I stated it's something I found it's not technically plagiarism. It's not easy to include the source because the actual, final, source is a PM in discord.
Although I let the author know that I am about to post this.
Eitherway, I edited the post.

Comment: So both 'OO' and '#%_%/#/' mean l (little L)? Either a shifting cipher or they are equal.

Comment: The fact that identical letters can be ciphered in a different way makes it impossible to solve for me.

Comment: does the clipher works differently when there is a vowel after the word and consonent after the word?

Answer (score 5):

The most likely plaintext I can find is:

> THANKS FOR BABYSITTING MY OC. I LIKE TUR???

Since the letter separator and word separator are given, begin by formatting the text to make it easier to work with. We also have five given letters, and some of them actually appear in the text, so write those in.

```
 H  E  L    L     O
O# #% OO #%_%/#/ O_O

       H                        |        O        
O_OO  O#  ~#  OO%  O_#  O#O#O   |   #_  O_O  OOO#  
      

/#/  %#  #  O/O/O  O/O/OO%  O%O#  O%#OO  OO_O  O%  O#O#  O  

             |              |        |  L
O#O  OOO_O   |   O%O#O  _   |   O##  |  OO  %O  O_#  ###  

 
#OO%O  O%%OO  #OOO  /O/O%O  O//OO/#/  /#
```

The pattern `.H.... .O.` suggests `THANKS FOR`, and the pattern `. L...` suggests `I LIKE`, so pencil those in. A long word following `THANKS FOR` is almost certainly a verb ending with `...ING`, so pencil that in too. The reappearance of `O_# = k` is encouraging.

```
 H  E  L    L     O
O# #% OO #%_%/#/ O_O

  t    H   a   n    k     s     |    f   O    r   
O_OO  O#  ~#  OO%  O_#  O#O#O   |   #_  O_O  OOO#  
      
                                                i   n    g
/#/  %#  #  O/O/O  O/O/OO%  O%O#  O%#OO  OO_O  O%  O#O#  O  

             |              |    i   |  L    i   k    e
O#O  OOO_O   |   O%O#O  _   |   O##  |  OO  %O  O_#  ###  

 
#OO%O  O%%OO  #OOO  /O/O%O  O//OO/#/  /#
```

These are some very bold assumptions, so we'll need to justify them. Observe that two of the penciled-in `i` are above `%O` and `O%`, which suggests the order of the symbols in each group does not matter. Also observe this `GHI` sequence:

```
G  H    I   I   I
O  O#  O##  O%  %O
```

This is enough to suggest that the substitution is based on the normal order of the alphabet and that each symbol has its own numeric value. On the assumption that the order in each group doesn't matter, the `RST` sequence is also promising:

```
R     S      T
OOO#  OOO##  OOO_
```

Pencil in a `t` and an `r` since they use the same collection of symbols.

```
  t    H   a   n    k     s     |    f   O    r   
O_OO  O#  ~#  OO%  O_#  O#O#O   |   #_  O_O  OOO#   
      
                                          t     i   n    g
/#/  %#  #  O/O/O  O/O/OO%  O%O#  O%#OO  OO_O  O%  O#O#  O  

             |              |    i   |  L    i   k    e
O#O  OOO_O   |   O%O#O  _   |   O##  |  OO  %O  O_#  ### 

               r
#OO%O  O%%OO  #OOO  /O/O%O  O//OO/#/  /#
```

Find some groups that only differ by a single symbol, and infer the value of that symbol.

```
r (OOO#)  s (OOO##)    #=1
g (O)     H (O#)       #=1
L (OO)    n (OO##)     #=1
L (OO)    n (OO%)      %=2
g (O)     i (O%)       %=2
H (O#)    k (O#_)      _=3
L (OO)    O (OO_)      _=3
O (OO_)   t (OOO_)     O=5
g (O)     L (OO)       O=5
```

The alphabet positions of G and L are 7 and 12, yet the symbol values give 5 and 10. Could an "empty group" have a value of 2? Given `L=OO` and `N=OO##`, assume `M=OO#` and the word `my`. The `y` also fits the inferred symbol values, where `OOO_O` = `55535` + 2 = 25 (Y):

```
  t    H   a   n    k     s     |    f   O    r   
O_OO  O#  ~#  OO%  O_#  O#O#O   |   #_  O_O  OOO#   
      
                                          t     i   n    g
/#/  %#  #  O/O/O  O/O/OO%  O%O#  O%#OO  OO_O  O%  O#O#  O  

 m     y     |              |    i   |  L    i   k    e
O#O  OOO_O   |   O%O#O  _   |   O##  |  OO  %O  O_#  ### 

               r
#OO%O  O%%OO  #OOO  /O/O%O  O//OO/#/  /#
```

Attempt to test the assumed values of the four symbols `#$_O` = `1235` and the base value of 2. The long word seems to produce a pattern with no words that match it, so this isn't quite correct. The double `t` is the only part that looks right.

```
      e  c                    o     t     t     i   n    g
/#/  %#  #  O/O/O  O/O/OO%  O%O#  O%#OO  OO_O  O%  O#O#  O
```

A pattern search for `......TTING` turns up the word `BABYSITTING`, which looks like a good match judging by how the repeated `O` symbols line up with letters later in the alphabet.

```
 b    a  b    y      s        i     t     t     i   n    g
/#/  %#  #  O/O/O  O/O/OO%  O%O#  O%#OO  OO_O  O%  O#O#  O
```

By assuming a mistake where an O was put in the wrong group, the `Y` and `S` make more sense, but it's still not clear how `b` is becoming both `#` and `/#/`.

```
 b    a  b    y      s        i     t     t     i   n    g
/#/  %#  #  O/O/OO  /O/OO%  O%O#  O%#OO  OO_O  O%  O#O#  O
```

Recall that "babysitting my OC" is a phrase used in the fanfiction community, where "OC" stands for "original character". Pencil in the `oc` with regret, assuming another mistake where an extra `O` was put into the group for no apparent reason. The word may be some other two-letter acronym (the symbol values suggest `TE`, whose meaning I'm not sure of.) Fill in the first two letters of the last word `TU` using the symbol values assumed earlier. Also write below each group its digit equivalents, their sum (plus the 2 for an empty group), and the corresponding letter.

```
#%_O
1235

 H   E   L    L       O
O#  #%  OO  #%_%/#/  O_O
51  12  55  1232/1/  535
 8   5  12    11     15
 H   E   L     K      O

  t    H   a   n    k     s     |    f   O    r   
O_OO  O#  ~#  OO%  O_#  O#O#O   |   #_  O_O  OOO#   
5355  51  ~1  552  531  51515       13  535  5551
 20    8   3   14   11    19         6   15   18
  T    H   C    N    K     S         F    O    R

 b    a  b    y      s        i     t     t     i   n    g
/#/  %#  #  O/O/O  O/O/OO%  O%O#  O%#OO  OO_O  O%  O#O#  O  
/1/  21  1  5/5/5  5/5/552  5251  52155  5535  52  5151  5
 3    5  3    17     24      15     20    20    9   14   7
 C    E  C     Q      Y       O      T     T    I    N   G

 m     y     |     o    c   |    i   |  L    i   k    e
O#O  OOO_O   |   O%O#O  _   |   O##  |  OO  %O  O_#  ### 
515  55535       52515  3       511     55  25  531  111  
 13    25          20   5        9      12   9   11   5
 M     Y            T   E        I       L   I   K    E

   t     u     r
#OO%O  O%%OO  #OOO  /O/O%O  O//OO/#/  /#
15525  52255  1555  /5/525  5//55/1/  /1
  20    21     18     19       18      3  
   T     U      R      S        R      C
```

I think this is as far as I can get. I can't tell what the slashes are supposed to mean. They might have a digit value of their own, or they might have some function where they appear in pairs and change the meaning of a symbol enclosed by `//`. It's tempting to assume the `~` is a negative sign, but since it occurs only once there can be no corroboration. For the last word, there are several `TUR...` words to choose from (I kind of like `TURPLE`, a cross between turquoise and purple), but it may not be any of them if it happens to be a person's name instead.